# Integrating Active Directory and OpenLDAP

Tags: windows, ubuntu, active-directory, ldap

It happens in many companies that they have Windows client/server and Linux client/server and for central management and integrity, if it could be possible to have central authorization and authentication strategy, it could bring more security and makes the administrators work easier, log management and log auditing is another good feature that can help us more.

I wonder is there any best practice to integrate OpenLDAP with active directory?
Am I right?
Can possibly this integration have more advantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join Linux machines to the AD DS domain directly, without needing to use other LDAP directories. Use  realmd to configure sssd relatively easily.

GPOs is a policy system for Windows machines. You will need to implement something else for Linux policy. Possibly commercial GPO for UNIX software, or a different configuration management tool.

Answer (score 2):

The project is called SAMBA, take a look here: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller

Simpli use openldap you get some limitations: https://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/integrate-active-directory-and-openldap (may you can find some think more recent)

Anyway what seems feet more to your question is this: https://www.freeipa.org/page/About